# Keys defined in dev.env.js are not accessible with webpack in vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js, environment-variables

The template is based on vuejs-webpack, and the build, config files are [here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/tree/develop/template/build), I have not modified any of these files.

Based on [Environment Variables](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/env.html) the keys defined in `dev.env.js` file must be accessible when running `npm run dev` in the app.

This is the content of my `dev.env.js`:

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  SAMPLE: '"XX"',
  AUTH_URL: '"http://localhost:3030"'
})
```

And when I try to access `AUTH_URL` in `App.vue` like this `process.env.AUTH_URL`, I receive `undefined`.

It seems to me whatever is defined in `dev.env.js` file will never become accessible when running `npm run dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `webpack.DefinePlugin` to define the variables you wish to share with your front end. Webpack its self does not expose `process` to the browser as this is a `node js function`.

```
const dev_env = require('dev.env.js)

plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env' : {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(dev_env.NODE_ENV)
    }
  })
]
```

Some variation of the above should work for you.

Comment: Hi @Ohgodwhy this only works in vue component but it is not accessible to other js file that is manually imported. But how do i achieve this otherwise?

Comment: @Photonic Webpack isn't responsible for the other file. Whenever you have variables like this in webpack, they'll alias them, so these aren't available globally to you. Consider requiring jQuery externally for those.

Answer (score 0):

If your run "npm run dev", then your new environment variable is only available after a restart of npm (Ctrl + C and again 'npm run dev').